# Can RadXE2 and RadXE5 be installed on a same computer and coexists

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe5

Just as the subject says: Can RadXE2 and RadXE5 be installed on a same computer and coexists?

In this case is a registered radxe2 and the idea is to test radxe5 using the same machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes (sorry too short for a real answer)

Comment: Yes, this works fine. I have a system that has D2007, XE, XE3, XE4, and XE5 installed with no issues. There have been other questions here about installing multiple versions of Delphi/RAD Studio on the same machine you can probably find with a search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Delphi versions on the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697916/multiple-delphi-versions-on-the-same-machine) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725383/install-both-delphi-2010-and-xe3-on-the-same-windows and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139844/can-delphi-2009-be-installed-on-the-same-machine-as-delphi-2006-or-delphi-2007  and probably many more

Comment: And the answer is yes. You can install all versions of Delphi on the same machine. And don't worry about the order in which you install them. What you need to do is remove all references to Delphi in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: No, you do not really need to clean PATH unless you want PATH to be clean. You will get `dcc32` resolved to latest installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you!!

Comment: I find that when I have a LOT (more than 3) of different Delphi versions installed, it's useful to do some PATH tidying. In fact I've even thought of making a tool for that purpose. Not essential in your case, but if you are using, say, 6 versions of Delphi, and 4 different versions of Visual Studio, and so on, and so on, you can sometimes find it hard (as a human) to keep all your paths straight.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Feel free to leave 10 Delphi versions in your path if you wish.

Comment: @WarrenP Visual Studio doesn't add to PATH because its installer is written by people that know what they are doing.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I've just been using machines where IT-departments added all the command-line paths for `devenv.exe` to my path for so long that I've forgotten that.